# Error: OCI runtime create failed when built an image and tried to run it on Docker

Tags: docker

I build an image with dockerfile and I tried to run it with specific network but I received the following error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"-net=overlay\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

any ideas how to solve this?

Thank you

Comment: @eyllanesc Can you re-check the command you are passing to run the docker container? Sharing snippets of it would help.

Comment: @MithunArunan I'm not the OP, I just edit the question

Comment: @Men always try to share dockerfile or at least base image. without such details, it's like showing the diseases but not the patient.

Comment: FROM httpd:2.4 ;

Comment: docker build -t aaa .  -> works!

Comment: docker run aaa --net=host  -> give me the following error:  docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"-net=host\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.

Comment: this should docker run --net=host aaa

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, it seems like you docker run command is incorrect, you are passing flag `--net=host` after the image name which is considered an argument for the container. so `--net=host` this replaced the `"httpd-foreground"` command. just try this to understand the scenario

```
 docker run httpd:2.4 echo "hi from the container; will print this message and I will be terminated"
```

[image]

See the last row and this will answer you and you will understand the concept.

```
docker build -t aaa .
```

Now run the container and it should work

```
docker run --net=host aaa
```

Comment: One last question, when I run:<docker run --net=ingress aaa>
I get the following error:  <docker: Error response from daemon: Could not attach to network ingress: rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = network ingress not manually attachable>   Suppose I want to run my container on Swarm using the master server, if I succeed to run the container on Overlay network- ingress, it will give me the option to see the container (aaa) on different nodes???

Comment: if it mapp with host network you should be able to access the container